# Efficient way of updating database daily on AWS RD

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

What's is the most efficient way of updating production database on AWS RDS, let say I have these databases?

```
DB_1 on AWS RDS (production)
------------------
Table A (updated continuously by frontend users)
Table B (same as above)

Table C (updated daily at 0:00 by mysqldump from DB_2)
Table D (same as above)
Table E (same as above)

DB_2 on AWS RDS (data processing)
------------------------------------
Table C (updated continuously)
Table D (updated continuously)
Table E (updated continuously)
```

Table C, D, E each has a few millions of rows. Existing rows are updated and 10,000~30,000 new rows are being added daily.

I think what I'm trying to achieve is different from Master-slave replication database concepts so I need advice on how to properly execute it.

> Definition: MySQL replication is a process that enables data from one
> MySQL database server (the master) to be copied automatically to one
> or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).

Comment: Why not replication ? Sounds like db1 should have its own tables, and also a live replica of db2 ? You can use set external master in the rds. Though consider why these need to be two separate databases ?

Comment: The intense reading and writing on Table C, D, E is affecting the performance of DB_1 throughout the day so decided to separate them. Also, DB_1 tables are already fixed and if possible not to change anything.

Comment: The real scenario is that currently only DB_1 exists, and all updates are done directly on all tables.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what advice you need and particularly what **programming** related advice you need (since you asked the question on SO and not on the DBA site). Using dumps to transfer data is a common enough solution.

Comment: Yes I think using dumps to replace the whole Table C, D, E is common. I am thinking to use AWS Lambda to execute it at 0:00.